# Evaluating differential forms(volume form) on vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

I was trying to evaluate the volume form $\Omega=dx_1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ on an vector fields $(X_1,\cdots, X_n)$ where each $X_i\in \Gamma(TM)$. Is there a quicker way to compute this instead of using definition of wedge product to write $\Omega$ as a tensor product?

Answer (score 1):

Write out each $X_b=\sum_{a=1}^n\xi_{ab}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$, then write $[\xi_{ab}]$ as an $n\times n$ matrix and calculate the determinant. More generally, if you have the differential $k$-form $dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}$, and you want to calculate its value on the vector fields $X_1,\dots, X_k$, then write out each $X_b=\sum_{a=1}^n\xi_{ab}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$, then write out the $n\times k$ matrix $[\xi_{ab}]$, and calculate the determinant of the $k\times k$ submatrix obtained by taking rows $i_1,\dots, i_k$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! May I ask how can one derive such formula or where is it coming from?

Comment: @Christina not sure if this is the most efficient way, but I hope you know that applying $dx^i$ on a vector field $X$ simply extracts the $i^{th}$ coefficient of $X$ when you expand it as $X=\sum\xi^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$. Now, write out the definition of the wedge product using $\text{Alt}$ and tensor products etc. Within a few lines of (admittedly a little annoying and tedious) calculations, you should immediately arrive at the formula for the determinant (the one using permutations, not the cofactor expansion).

Comment: Alternatively, if you look at this from the correct perspective, this follows immediately from the abstract definition of the determinant (for example, Loomis and Sternberg's chapter 7 has this definition), which roughly speaking says that for an endomorphism $T:V\to V$ and any volume form $\mu$ on $V$, $\det T$ is the unique constant such that $T^*\mu = (\det T) \cdot \mu$. (And it is easily shown this constant is independent of $\mu$, so this is well-defined).

Comment: That's very helpful! By the way, is there a reference of the calculation using tensors and Alt you just said or is it purely a computation one should do by themselves?

Comment: Most of the time, this sort of thing is left as an exercise for the reader :) I first encountered as an exercise while studying from Spivak's Calculus on manifolds. But really, the idea is that the wedge product is alternating. The determinant is also alternating, so it's natural to expect a very close connection between the two (because the space of top-degree alternating forms on a vector space is one-dimensional).